# Sort based on where the search string found

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to sort the search result based on where the search string is found? Basically I am using Django Rest and trying to show the results on top if the search string is found at the beginning.

For example,

```
values = [ "another test", "test", "something", "teeest"]
search_string="te"
result=["another test", "test", "teeest"]
```

I want to bring the last two in the front as it has "te" at the begining like

```
result=[ "test", "teeest", "another test"]
```

Comment: You tagged the question with Django, are you looking to order a queryset?

Comment: yes, I wanted to sort the queryset

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` with `key` as `str.startswith`:

```
sorted(values, key=lambda x: not x.startswith(search_string))
# or without `not`
sorted(values, key=lambda x: x.startswith(search_string), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['test', 'teeest', 'another test', 'something']
```

Comment: any idea how can I use it for django

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `result` twice, once for items that start with `search_string`, and another with those that do not:

```
[i for i in result if i.startswith(search_string)] + [i for i in result if not i.startswith(search_string)]
```